# how to get the column count in multi-column layout in webkit

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, css, multiple-columns

I have some static HTML content. I need to format it using multiple columns, which are then presented as pages to the user. I use something quite simple which boils down to this:

```
bodyID = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
bodyID.style.width = desiredWidth;
totalHeight = bodyID.offsetHeight;
pageCount = Math.ceil(totalHeight/desiredHeight);
bodyID.style.width = desiredWidth*pageCount;
bodyID.style.height = desiredHeight;
bodyID.style.webkitColumnGap = 0;
bodyID.style.webkitColumnCount = pageCount;
```

Now, my problem is that webKit honors the height attribute as it should and can create more columns than asked for if the content does not fit into `pageCount` number of columns.

I need to be able to get the number of columns afterwards to implement paging correctly. However the value of `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitColumnCount` does not differ from `pageCount` even if there are more columns.

Any ideas, how to get the total number of rendered columns?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution turned out to be much simpler than I thought. It was just a matter of getting the actual width of the page using `bodyID.scrollWidth` and then dividing by `desiredWidth` to get the actual number of pages.

Hope this helps somebody.